# Easy way to sync VM to real server

Tags: virtualization

I want to run a CentOS server, and was thinking I would run CentOS in a VM to test things first. Once I'm happy, I want my changes to move over to the OS running on hardware.

Where should I start?

Thanks!

Comment: What virtualization product are you using?

Comment: VirtualBox right now, but I'm happy to change products if it would make this easier.

Answer (score 1):

Start by using a configuration management system, such as [Puppet](http://reductivelabs.com/puppet).  Describe the changes you want to make, test those changes on the staging VM, then when you're happy with them apply them to the live machine.

Comment: Agreed.  CFEngine is another good choice for this.

Comment: On the contrary, cfengine is a pretty poor configuration management system by the standards of what else is out there.

Answer (score 0):

A simple rsync script could probably do most of what you want. If you've got databases, or stuff like that, you might need a script to dump, copy and import them, but it's hard to give a better answer without more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with a source code management system like cvs, subversion, git or so you can keep the entire /etc/ under revision inside the VM. In general 99% of configuration files are in /etc. Once you are happy with your tests and want to switch to the physical server simply install CentOS there and do checkout in /etc/. Voila! If you have other work directories like /var/www you can have them in the file repository too.
I recommend using subversion, because it's easier to start with and it handles better than cvs special files.
This way you can clone interesting changes and have a history of what you did.